# Samsung s5 and s6 application access/startup time or log

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Someone physically accessed my Samsung s5 and s6 phones' gallery and camera without my permission. How can I see when e.g. gallery was accessed? Is there any log left behind when applications are started?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, rooting the phone, accessing usage stats and running busybox's /system/xbin/stat on files but no avail, the Android doesn't update atime for files and usage stats didn't show last open time of apps. Had to give up.